# How do I make trillian forget my password?

Tags: trillian

I use trillian at work and cannot find a way for it to forget my password. It just autologs me. I guess I checked remember me the first time but I would very much like to make it forget.

I guess I could uninstall and whipe everything but I would hope there is a "normal" way.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well. Not 5 seconds after asking I find it.

Select 'Switch User' from the menu, then hover over your name and select the small pencil which appears.